# Dreamweaver SSH denial on Linux Whm at account level

Tags: ssh, cpanel, dreamweaver, whm, sshd

I am having a problem that is really frustrating in that I can no longer connect to my server user accounts through Dreamweaver using SFTP. It keeps saying username or password is incorrect, but it definitely is.

*Edit: I am on a linux server using WHM / Cpanel.

So I have access to root, but I use various accounts for different projects. Under each account a pair of keys have been generated and are being shown as "Authorised" in cpanel, so I know authorisation isnt the issue.

In Dreamweaver I am attempting to connect to the server via SFTP on port 22.
Username: @Account username
Key: Private Key authorised in cpanel SSH for that specific account
Passphrase: I have used both key passphrase and account username password - both fail.

Host Access Control in WHM is set to allow my IP on port 22.

Here is a copy of my sshd.conf

```
       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.
# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.
# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
# SELinux about this change.
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
#
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none
# This system is following system-wide crypto policy. The changes to
# crypto properties (Ciphers, MACs, ...) will not have any effect here.
# They will be overridden by command-line options passed to the server
# on command line.
# Please, check manual pages for update-crypto-policies(8) and sshd_config(5).
# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO
# Authentication:
#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10
PubkeyAuthentication yes
# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none
#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
HostbasedAuthentication yes
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes
# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication no
# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes
# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#GSSAPIEnablek5users no
# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in RHEL and may cause several
# problems.
UsePAM yes#AllowAgentForwarding
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
# It is recommended to use pam_motd in /etc/pam.d/sshd instead of PrintMotd,
# as it is more configurable and versatile than the built-in version.
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none
# no default banner path
#Banner none
# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem sftp  /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
UseDNS no
DenyGroups cpaneldemo cpanelsuspended
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Was nothing to do with the sshd file. The SSH KEy was saving as a text file, which was causing the issue.

id_rsa.txt instead of just being recognised as a key file.